# Automatically take screenshot in every 5 min in all OS

Tags: c#, cross-platform, desktop-application, avalonia

I'm developing a cross-platform desktop application using Avalonia, in which I want to take  screenshots of the desktop after every 5 min. By googling I get the code to take screenshot in windows OS.

```
   Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
   using(Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
   {
        using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
             g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
        }
        bitmap.Save("test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
   }
```

But how can I do it in Linux and Mac OS.
Anyone please help me.

Comment: This looks like a good place to start: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shell-script-to-take-a-screenshot/